# Bootstrap Popover with Ajax is not working UNLESS I CANCEL AJAX

Tags: ajax, popover

I saw this problem on a few posts here but non helped me (sorry if I'm missing something) :

I am creating popovers dynamically on my page (with ajax pagination). gthe content of the popover is also generated with ajax.

but in order to see the generated HTML in each popover, I have to press the button twice because the first time it will only show an empty box.

**html generated popover buttons:**

```
<input data-html="true" onclick="gtfrnd(this);" type="button" data-toggle="popover" title="invite a friend" value="invite a friend" data-content=""></input>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

**js function**

```
function getfrnd(varb)
{


    var emailsleft=0;

        $.ajax({
                  url: "getfrnd.php"
                }).done(function( data ) {

            emailsleft=data;

$(varb).attr("data-content","<div><input placeholder='friend@email.com' value='' id='friendsemail'></input><br /><input type='button' style='font: normal 13px tahoma !important;border-radius: 5px;background: blue;padding: 5px;' value='Send (you are left with "+emailsleft+" invitations)' onclick='getfrnd2(this);'></input></div>");

             })

}
```

Important: If I remove the ajax function and simply tells it to insert text without ajax, it does work!!
It is the ajax that causes the problem

Like that, it does work: !!

```
function getfrnd(varb)
{
    var emailsleft=3;

    $(varb).attr("data-content","<div><input placeholder='friend@email.com' value='' id='friendsemail'></input><br /><input type='button' style='font: normal 13px tahoma !important;border-radius: 5px;background: blue;padding: 5px;' value='Send (you are left with "+emailsleft+" invitations)' onclick='getfrnd2(this);'></input></div>");

}
```

With the ajax, it will show the correct content only on the second time the button is being clicked.
any way to make the ajax function does work before the first time the popover is being fired?